Asynchronous Path $record value is current values or previously committed values?
As it says in the title couldn't see any info on this definitively specifying which way it works or maybe I am blind? but when an asynchronous path runs on a flow is the record values in the $record variable the record as it exists right now or what was actually committed to the database at the end of the transaction?
Doesn't really matter either I have to do a get a get request to get the current status or it is the status I already want.


It implies that when the Async path runs, $Record will have the state it ends up with after being successfully commited in the original transaction.
source: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_automate_flow_builder_asynchronous_path.htm&release=234&type=5
